# How can you use polymorphic_path inside a jbuilder view with custom prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jbuilder

Trying to generate the path for a polymorphic association. I've tried, but keep getting errors.

```
json.(payment, :created_at, :type, :check_number, :amount_cents, :payable_type, :payable_id)

# json.payable_path Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_path(:custom_name, payment.payable)
```

Must I create a `payable_path` method on the payment model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it for a comment in my app. On the comment model `commentable` is a polymorphic association.

Here are a couple lines from my `_comment.json.jbuilder`

```
json.extract! comment, :owner, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
json.commentable_path polymorphic_url(comment.commentable)
```

Comment: I was using that too, but had to add in a prefix, but was missing the array brackets, so that's what sent me down the wrong....PATH! </knee slapper>

Answer (score 0):

I could not get polymorphic path to work so I implemented a getter on the payment:

```
  def payable_path
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("edit_#{payable_type.downcase}_path", payable)
  end
```

Not saying this answers the question, but it is an option get things done.